# How to make the inherited function to call the derived class function without virtual functions

Tags: c++

Let's assume I have class `A` and `B` as follows:

```
class A
{
    public:
        void function_1(){ /*other codes*/; function_2();};
        void function_2();
 };

class B:public A
{
   public:
   void function_2(); // this function is reimplementation of A::function_2()
};
```

Now assume in the main code I have

```
B objB;
objB.function_1();
```

From my test if I leave the code as above, it will still call `A::function_2()` internally when `objB.function_1()` is called.

I want `objB.function_1()` will internally call the `B::function_2()`, not `A::function_2()`. Is it possible to do it provided that I cannot change the code of `A` class?

Comment: You don't *override* but *hide* method. Do you want to use virtual methods ?

Comment: This is not how inheritance works. Learn about `virtual`, `override`, overloading and hiding of members.

Comment: There are no overridden functions in this snippet. You should reread the relevant section in your book.

Comment: I understand the concept of virtual but like I said I cannot change code of class A

Comment: The **override** is not essential, but is advisable. However, what is required is that the base class method must be declared as **virtual**

Comment: If you do understand that stuff, it should be clear that virtual function calls cannot happen in a non-virtual context.

Comment: If you want `B::function_1()` to behave differently from `A::function_1()` then you just have to implement `B::function_1()` to do what you want. However, since you can't change `A`, you will not be able to achieve polymorphic behavior this way, if that's desirable for your situation.

Comment: You should consider rather or not inheritance is the right tool for this job. The uses for public inheritance without polymorphism in a data class is limited and very misleading for the user. You probably don't want to pass `B` where an `A` is expected. Have you thought of simply giving `B` a `A` member?

Comment: `B::function_2()` ***cannot*** _override_ `A::function_2()` unless `A::function_2()` is virtual. Commenting as such doesn't change anything. You can get `objB.function_1();` to call `B::function_2()` by _also hiding_ `A::function_1()` .... but that stil is ***NOT*** overriding!

Comment: Oh OK so I used the wrong term it is not overridden function but hided function

Comment: @rudky It's not just a wrong term - the semantic difference is ***very*** important. It's the difference between doing what you want to do and ***not being able to*** do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do it provided that I cannot change the code of `A` class?

As others already pointed out in comments, that's not possible without making function `A::function_2()` a `virtual` function.

So if you can't change `class A` that's not possible.

---

One option is to reimplement `A::function_1()` in your derived `class B`.

Though you could provide a wrapper class for `A` that provides virtual functions which can be overridden in derived classes and makes that easier for future inheritors:

```
class AWrap {
protected:
    A wrappedA;
public:
    virtual void function_1() {
        // Reimplement A::function_1() "other codes"
        function_2();
    }
    virtual void function_2() {
        wrappedA.function_2();
    }
};

class B : public AWrap {
public:
    void function_2() override {
         // Implement the B specific stuff
    }
};
```